# How to validate password while typing in android

Tags: android

I'm creating an android app. 
I have a registration form in that app. Registration form is having three fields like `email`, `password` and `confirm password`. 
 I want to validate `email` while typing and also need to check whether password and confirm password are matching while typing. How can I do that in android?

Can anyone help me on this issue? 
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Answer (score 0):

Add textchange listener to `EditText`

```
passwordEdt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

  }

  @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

  }

  @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String enteredText = s.toString();
    //do validation here
  }
});
```